# Backup em MySQL WorkBench

Tags: mysql

Preciso fazer uma modificação no banco de dados. Queria saber como faço um backup em MySQL WorkBench, e como faço para restaurá-lo depois em caso de erros.

Também se possível gostaria de algumas dicas de bons hábitos para realizar este tipo de tarefa, e algumas dicas!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vá no menu `Server`, `Data Export`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em `Object Selection`, selecione o banco que você deseja fazer o Bkp. 
Lá embaixo, em Options, selecione a opção que deseja para fazer o salvamento: 
`Export to Dump` ou `Export to Self-Conteined File`. Selecione o caminho desejado e clique em `Start Export.`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para você fazer a importação, selecione `Data Import` no menu.

Selecione o tipo de importação e o caminho onde você salvou o arquivo `.sql`
Selecione o BD onde você quer restaurar e clique em `Start Import`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado!